# Where does Sticky Notes save data?

Tags: windows, sticky-notes

I lost my Sticky Notes after upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1.

I still have my `Windows.old` folder, which has user folders in it, and so `AppData` as well.

I'm hoping to recover a particular note, but need to know where to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be found in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the file format, but was able to zip my current `.snt` file, copy over the old one, save the note I needed, and then restore the newer file.